# How to access service reference methods

Tags: c#, wsdl, service-reference

I added service reference to my project (it is my first time doing it) using WSDL and it shows up under connected services but I am unable to access its methods. So reference is called svc_test and it has public interface called TestGroup which has all needed methods. 
I tried to do:

```
using(var svc = new svc_test.TestGroup())
```

it tells me cannot create an instance of abstract class or interface TestGroup and TestGroup used in using statement must be implicitly disposable.
Then I tried to do and a least I was able to access methods but now it says unassigned local variable used how should I assign `test` variable?

```
svc_test.TestGroup test;
var response = test.login("name","password");
```

I tried to assign it like this:

```
svc_test.TestGroup test = new svc_test.TestGroup();
```

I get same error same Cannot not create an instance of abstract class or interface TestGroup. Please help.

Comment: WSDL-generated clients normally have the Client suffix. Are you sure you shouldn't be using something like `TestGroupClient`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto where can I find it? Is it in WSDL?

Comment: Normally it would be `new svc_test.TestGroupClient`, VS creates that class for you

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks a lot!!!